# Reading Matrixes - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, matrix

I am trying to read a matrix. I have taken a look at Google and I see everyone does something similar as I did. It compiles, but when I introduce the values for the first position, it says: Segmentation Fault: 11. I have tried this code in Linux and in Mac OSX. And I get the same error.

This is my function:

I have this struct:

```
struct Matri {
    string idm;         // name of vector
    int rows;
    int columns;
    string id;
    vector<vector<int> > matrix;
};


void readMatrix(Matri* m){    

    cout << "Introduce the name of the matrix" << endl;

    cin >> m->idm;

    cout << "Introduce number of rows: " << endl;
    cin >> m->rows;
    cout << "Introduce number of columns: " << endl;
    cin >> m->columns;

    m->matrix.resize(m->rows*m->columns);
    cout << "Size: " << m->matrix.size() << endl;

    for (int i = 1; i <= m->rows; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j <= m->columns; j++){
            cout << "Size of matrix: " << m->matrix.size() << endl;
            cout << "Introduce values for position:  " <<  i << ", " << j << endl;
            cin >> m->matrix[i][j]; //THIS IS WHAT DOES NOT WORK. It says Segmentation Fault 11.
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Your loops should be from 0 to n - 1, not from 1 to n. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I have the same problem even changing that!

Comment: @user3369375 ... and the other problem is, you're not giving enough information in your question!

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
m->matrix.resize(m->rows*m->columns);
```

you make a vector of `m->rows*m->columns` vectors, each of which is empty.
The crash is caused by your attempting to accesss the elements in these empty vectors.

You need something like this:

```
m->matrix.resize(m->rows);
for (auto i = m->matrix.begin(); i != m->matrix.end(); ++i)
{
    i->resize(m->columns);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This was the way to do it!